# Facebook Social Login Plugin and: Editing and positioning user information, and storing it for later

Tags: html, css, facebook-social-plugins

Please forgive me beacause I'm a noob.

I've been able to get the fb-login-button to appear at the top of my site using facebook social plugins found here:

developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Currently when you log into my site shows the following:

http://s11.postimage.org/4i1255843/fb_Login_Mysite.jpg

However I want to setup my site to be more like the RT site and just display the persons first name and and also can display some other info around the site like this:

http://s12.postimage.org/6cm7ylyn1/Rotton_Tom.jpg

**My question is:**
I want to be able to show or hide specific facebook information from the person that is logged in like their name, how many friends they have that use the site and then place that information around the site or on other pages as I choose. Does anyone know how to do this or where some documentation would be on it?

Also when users login/register using facebook I'd like to store their information they give me somewhere like their email address, name, etc.. Does anyone know how I can store this information on a database or other place? Does it get stored in my facebook application?

Answer (score 0):

For your first name and all the information you want to display, first you need to create MySQL database and create a table within it. You can use phpMyAdmin to create it automatically.

Then, you need to connect your database with your PHP site, where your register and login code is used.

You said you are a noob, so I didn't go into detail, becaouse you have great video tutorials right [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE134D877783367C7&feature=plcp). Just watch these videos and you will know everything you need to know about creating login & register page.

To create a summary, you need to learn PHP to get ceratin elements and manipulate them (show them on your site etc.).

Hope I helped!